# PowerShell - Changing the PipelineVariable name

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell you can change the name of the variable used as the item in an iterative block, such as:

```
dir -recurse *.snippet -OutVariable snippets

$snippets | Where-Object -PipelineVariable fn { $fn.Length -ge 6000 } | select FullName
```

That code doesn't work, but you get the idea. I think it doesn't work because the `-PipelineVariable` argument must be specified in the previous CmdLet.

My question is, what CmdLet do I use to pipe the contents of `$snippets`?

i.e. when I just run `$snippets` it implicitly just spews the contents out into the pipeline, but what CmdLet does this?

I've tried many, and many seem to output the array on the screen, but when piped into the `Where-Object` the where clause doesn't work, it's like its looking at the outer array object instance and not each item.

Luke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it only makes sense to use `-PipelineVariable` if you have more than one step in the pipeline, to preserve object from earlier pipeline elements.

Anyway: in this case I would use `Write-Output`:

```
Write-Output $snippets -PipelineVariable fn | Where-Object { $fn.Length -ge 6000 }
```

Comment: `Write-Output` "Sends the specified objects to the next command in the pipeline" -- easy when you know. Nearest I got was `Out-Default`. Thanks and I take your point about `PipelineVariable` it was more a learning exercise than any legit need.